$S$-modular transformation to the torus partition function
My general objective is to obtain the Cardy formula (see this related question) through the saddle-point approximation, nonetheless, I'm confused in how apply the $S$-modular transformation to the torus partition function.
Context, notation and my procedure
The torus is generated by the complex pair $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$, which forms its fundamental domain $w$ in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, in the form
\begin{align}
 \label{eq: Torus definition}
 w\sim w+\alpha_1 m+\alpha_2 n\,,
\end{align}
where $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$. An $S$-transformation is defined as
\begin{align}
 \label{eq: S-modular transformation}
 S:\quad \tau'=-\frac{1}{\tau}\,,
\end{align}
where $\tau$ is the modular parameter $\tau=\alpha_2/\alpha_1$. This implies that the complex number $w$ transforms as
\begin{align}
 \label{eq: S-modular}
 \begin{split}
  w\sim w+\alpha_1 &\rightarrow w'\sim w'+\alpha_2'\,,\\
  w\sim w+\alpha_2 &\rightarrow w'\sim w'-\alpha_1'\,.
 \end{split}
\end{align}
$S$-transformations are important due the fact that they generate a swap between the angular and thermal cycles of a conformal field theory. We define the angular and thermal cycles of the torus. They are given by
\begin{align}
 \label{eq: Angular and thermcal cycles}
 \begin{split}
  \text{Angular cycle}:\quad \left(t,\phi\right)&\sim \left(t,\phi+2\pi\ell\right)\,,\\
  \text{Thermal cycle}:\quad \left(t,\phi\right)&\sim\left(t-i\beta,\phi-i\theta\right)\,.
 \end{split}
\end{align}
Thus, we recognize the complex pairs $\alpha_1=\left(0,2\pi\ell\right)$ and $\alpha_2=\left(-i\beta,-i\theta\right)$. Applying an $S$-modular transformation, we obtain
\begin{equation}
 \label{eq: S-modular coordinates}
 \begin{alignedat}{2}
  \text{S-angular cycle:}\quad &\left(t,\phi\right)\sim\left(t,\phi+2\pi\ell\right)&&\rightarrow \left(t',\phi'\right)\sim\left(t'-i\beta',\phi-i\theta'\right)\,,\\
  \text{S-thermal cycle:}\quad &\left(t,\phi\right)\sim\left(t-i\beta,\phi-i\theta\right)&&\rightarrow \left(t',\phi'\right)\sim\left(t',\phi'-2\pi\ell\right)\,.
 \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
Therefore, we can find the modular parameter
\begin{align}
\tau=\frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_1}=\frac{-i\beta-i\theta}{2\pi\ell}=-i\frac{\beta+\theta}{2\pi\ell}\,.
\end{align}
Now, since $\tau'=-1/\tau$, we readily find
\begin{align}
\beta'+\theta'=\frac{4\pi^2\ell^2}{\beta+\theta}\,.
\end{align}
We are almost done to implement the latter in the partition function. The latter is
\begin{align}
Z(\beta,\theta)=\mathrm{Tr}\left(e^{-\beta M-\theta J}\right)\,.
\end{align}
If $H=M+\frac{\theta}{\beta}J$ fulfills $H\left|\left.0\right>\right.=\left(M_0+\frac{\theta}{\beta}J_0\right)\left|\left.0\right>\right.$, where $M_0$ and $J_0$ stand for the mass and angular momentum of the ground state, then, in the low-temperature regime, the partition function is dominated by
\begin{align}
Z\left(\beta,\theta\right)\simeq e^{-\beta M_0-\theta J_0}\,.
\end{align}
Applying an $S$-modular transformation to the latter, we arrive to
\begin{align}
Z\left(\beta',\theta'\right)\simeq e^{-\beta' M_0-\theta' J_0}\,.
\end{align}
Replacing, we arrive to
\begin{align}
Z\left(\beta',\theta'\right)\simeq e^{-\left(\frac{4\pi^2\ell^2}{\beta+\theta}-\theta'\right)M_0-\left(\frac{4\pi^2\ell^2}{\beta+\theta}-\beta'\right)J_0}=e^{-\frac{4\pi^2\ell^2}{\beta+\theta}\left(M_0+J_0\right)+\theta'M_0+\beta'J_0}\,.
\end{align}
I don't know how to proceed, since I still have $\beta'$ and $\theta'$ terms that I cannot get rid through the $S$-modular transformation $\beta'+\theta'=\frac{4\pi^2\ell^2}{\beta+\theta}$.
